# How do I get rid of houttuynia (heartleaf/lizard tail)?

Tags: weed-control, invasive

A previous owner left me with a garden full of [Houttuynia cordata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houttuynia_cordata) (also called hearleaf/lizard tail/chameleon plant), an invasive weed that I've been trying to eradicate.  I can't believe it is sold in garden stores; it's far too aggressive.  It sends these little whitish lateral shoots about 12 inches deep in all directions and thereby spreads under fences and into all the other flowers in the bed.

How can I get rid of it completely?

[image]

<sub>Source: Wikimedia commons</sub>

Comment: To go along with ["winwaed" answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/305/how-do-i-get-rid-of-houttuynia-heartleaf-lizard-tail/688#688) you might want to take a look at: [Houttuynia cordata (shrub)](http://www.issg.org/database/species/ecology.asp?si=854) from Global Invasive Species Database, via [USDA Plants - Houttuynia cordata](http://plants.usda.gov/java/profile?symbol=HOCO3)

Answer (score 8):

I think you are going to have a lot of hard work ahead of you! This is true of quite a few invasives.

Here's a general website on invasives that lists quite a few including *Houttuynia*:

http://www.dgsgardening.btinternet.co.uk/wayward.htm

For this general type of spreading, it recommends physical removal and the use of systemic herbicide to kill all root parts. It notes that the rhizomes for *Houttuynia* are notorious for getting embedded within other root systems.

I don't know if it flowers, but also decapitate flower heads before they seed.

Comment: It does flower.