# What is this white flower with stacked petals?

Tags: identification

I can't identify this short-ish plant with one white flower with has stacked petals. It also has green, vaguely-heart-shaped leaves that have a pink-burgundy rim, the stalk is also burgundy. I live in England in the East-Midlands, but I'm not sure if this is a native plant or not.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [*Houttuynia cordata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houttuynia_cordata), possibly var. ["Plena"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Houttunyia%20cordata%20%22plena%22), which was the only variety that I could find with multiple rows of bracts as shown in your photograph.

Identifying characteristics for me are the red-tinged leaf borders and stems, the heart-shaped leaves and the pattern of the veins on the leaves. Compare the photograph in my own question about it: [What is this (allegedly) mosquito-repellent trailing plant with dark green heart-shaped leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4326/what-is-this-allegedly-mosquito-repellent-trailing-plant-with-dark-green-heart)

[image]

This plant has been [mentioned a few times](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=Houttuynia%20cordata) before on this site. In summary, it can be extremely invasive in damp conditions; keep it in a pot if you want it, otherwise be prepared for a difficult battle to control or remove it.