# Does anyone know what type of plant this is with heart shaped leaves?

Tags: identification

this plant is taking over my rock garden and I would like to get rid of it[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Yur.jpg)

Comment: Does it have a smell when you pick it?

Comment: I think it may be pokeweed, in which case it's poisonous when eaten. If you have pets or small children, you may want to keep them away from it in case I'm correct.

Comment: Is this it? https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4326/what-is-this-allegedly-mosquito-repellent-trailing-plant-with-dark-green-heart

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Houttuynia Cordata, or Chameleon Plant. (Also known by other names.) Used in Eastern medicine but considered an invasive plant by many who have it in their gardens.

Comment: Very invasive; my biggest problem weed ( and I planted it).