# Anyone know what this is? Should I pull it?

Tags: identification

Can someone please tell me what this is? I dont know if i should pull it or leave it. I have 4 popping up in my garden.[image]

Comment: More information may make it more likely to get a good response. Things like; where on the globe is the plant located, is this the only one or are there others just like it around. Any other information about the plant and conditions may be helpful in getting a response.

Comment: It looks related to swiss chard and spinach to me, but I don't think it's either. I don't know what it is. (I don't recommend eating it, without knowing what it is, as it might be toxic.)

Comment: Janis, now that a week has gone by, has the plant gotten larger? In your photo, it almost looks like it could be Japanese Knotweed or a relative. If it IS knotweed, it should be much taller now. If the plant has grown significantly - higher, wider or both, please edit your question and add a new photo. That'll make it easier to identify.

Comment: Houttuynia cordata most likely. https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4326/what-is-this-allegedly-mosquito-repellent-trailing-plant-with-dark-green-heart